# Panning a layout with imageviews on it

Tags: android

I have been puzzled by how to approach this for a while. I have Framelayout  with over 20 image views on it. I want to be able to pan the framelayout. Basically, touching and dragging causes the background image to pan (and the 20 image views to move along).

This is similar to what strategy games do (you have map and buildings).

I read all about panning and zooming and they all talking about doing this for single imageview. In my case, not only it is a layout but also it has other views.

How do I approach this? Any pointers ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a github project for zooming and panning although its for View Groups it would be easy to change for a View.
Check it out let me know if you have a question it is unfinished but works.

https://github.com/Xjasz/AndroidZoomableViewGroup

Copy the class and extends FrameLayout instead of ListView.
Then make sure in your XML to use the class instead of a FrameLayout.

Comment: This is a great class to use. Amazing! The only 2 issues I found are 1) It does not scale the framelayout background image to see the details of the background,  and 2) The scaling center happens always at the top right not where you pinch and zoom

Comment: Sorry I mean scaling happens at top left

Comment: Ya sorry I just haven't had time to finish it if you want I can add you as a contributor :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a TouchInterceptor/Custom view where on touch, you offset the view from its parent by the delta of the current touch coords from the last touch coords.